# Best practice for multi section form

Tags: .net, maui

Recently, my team developed an app for doing survey. They have more than 10 surveys and each survey has hefty number of questions. For experience purpose, we decided to divide each form into sections.

Our approach on the implementation is that every form will have multiple xaml page such as:

- Form1 > Section1.xaml, Section2.xaml, Section3.xaml, ...
- Form2 > Section1.xaml, Section2.xaml, Section3.xaml, ...

Each page will be a singleton.

But few issues were raised inside the development:

1. **our initial idea**: a filling of a form needs to have a single viewmodel.

   **reality**: while filling a form, viewmodel for every form can't be set to *transient* as every time the section page is changed, the viewmodel will reset. So we have to set it to *singleton*.

   **drawback**: after submit, we need to reset each properties inside the viewmodel one by one to be used in the next filling (We can't find a way to reset dotnet singleton).
2. `MauiProgram.cs` file consist of hefty amount of singleton declaration as a form can have up to 15 sections. This also making the project structure having an unsettling look.

We do realize that there exist some workaround like using our own singleton so that special logic can be added, or simply using region in MauiProgram.cs so that the heft number of declarations can be grouped neatly.

But is there best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: If each sections of a form are related why not grouping them in an object and making it a singleton ? This way you could reset each section by creating new objects then the form is submited

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> They have more than 10 surveys and each survey has hefty number of
> questions.

You can try to create a static global class (e.g. `MySourceData.cs`) to store the data for your surveys and questions.

In your ViewModel, you can initialize the instance of your viewmodel with above global class.

After submitting, you can assign new data to your viewmode with the data from the global class( `MySourceData.cs`).

**Note:**

Since we cannot see the detail code of your app, but the above method is also commonly used.

Comment: Hi @Averrous Saloom, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.